# How do I make description editable on a custom rally kanban board app (rally gridboard)

Tags: extjs, rally

I found the Rally Kanban source in GitHub and made some minor changes and built my own custom app. The new Rally Kanban app uses Rally.ui.gridboard.GridBoard (no docs yet?). Currently only the name of the story is editable.  Can I make other fields editable as well?

There does not seem to be docs for GridBoard yet: [Rally 2.0rc2 API](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api)

Also I would like to drop the label from the description field.

Answer (score 0):

A request to make other fields editable on a card has come up before, but currently only Name and Owner can be edited. Other fields, including Description are not editable. I don't think there is a config property to drop a label.